# Multiselect Recyclerview List

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Good day all,

I have a list of items that i want the user to be able select say 5 out of the 10 items and with all 5 be able to send some data off to a webservice.

i found [This](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/recyclerview-part-2-choice-modes/) and [This](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/statelistdrawables-for-recyclerview-selection/)

but neither of them worked or the GitHub Repo is non existent (the second one).

Does anyone have any other tuts on how to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Would you prefer to use a multiselect ListView instead of Recyclerview List  ?

Comment: i've already implemented other features around the recyclerview, would be a ton or work to have to undo all that?

Comment: Yea, it would. But if you still don't find an answer. You can then revert to ListView

Comment: ok im not going to accept as an answer, but do u have tuts around that incase i dont come right?

Comment: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-delete-multiple-selected-items-listview-tutorial/

Comment: Use checkbox with your Recyclerview item and write oncheckchange listener inside the view holder and set the value to list which is set to adapter.

Answer (score 0):

What is going on with your proplem? 
Is the video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7du30yAL6rI) as your expectation?

In this example, I create an empty class and simple recyclerview.

The view item will handle user click behaviour. If user selected item the click again the item would not select and otherwise. When this action is happening, we have a listener to send to MainActivity (implemented `onItemChangeListener` a method of interface that is defined in `adapter`)

In the MainActivity, I create a layout with recyclerView, delete button, and no items labels. The delete button will process delete and update the list data.

The source code is at: https://github.com/liemvo/Example_RecycleMultiSelected